# Where to get information about array fields in $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, variables, globals, http

I just started to learn PHP and doing things with WordPress and I am a bit confused about information in Codex. Was told that Codex got all info I required but I got stuck with it.

**What array fields are in `$_REQUEST` in WordPress?** Can not find it in Codex.

E.g.: people use
`$my_contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];`
How do they know `$_REQUEST` has `'contact'` field?

Is there any workflow to find informations about variables which are not described in Codex? Should I print off all the array to see what fields are inside?

Google does not help me.. about $_REQUEST.

Comment: Close-voted as *off-topic*. This is an **HTTP** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 10):

This is mostly pure PHP, but it does have WordPress twist.

PHP has number of [*superglobal* variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), that contain information relevant to current request. Out of those:

- `$_GET` contains info from URL (HTTP GET request)
- `$_POST` info from form submission (HTTP POST request)
- `$_COOKIES` about cookies set
- and `$_REQUEST` is combination of the above (according to docs `$_COOKIES` can be commonly configured to skip for better security)

However WP enforces its own logic - during load process [`wp_magic_quotes()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_magic_quotes) processes variables to emulate [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) setting and enforces `$_REQUEST` to contain combination of `$_GET` and `$_POST`, no matter what PHP configuration says.

So in WordPress environment it will contain GET and/or POST request data. What data exactly that is will depend entirely which page you are on and what is happening on it.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note about `$_REQUEST`: Whenever you see this in a code you know it is written by a beginner. As @Rarst explained it is a combination of multiple sources. But why should anyone want to process data which should be send per POST *only* if they are in fact send per GET?

Do not accept data from an input stream you haven’t declared previously. Use `$_GET` if you want GET and `$_POST` if you want POST. Nothing else.

To access POSTed data without WordPress’ intervention use the input stream wrapper [`php://input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).
So, instead of …

```
// already changed by WordPress when you get it
$data = $_POST;
```

… use …

```
// Doesn’t work with 'enctype="multipart/form-data"'
$data = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
```

And don’t forget [data validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned printing off the array, so you might know how to do this already.  You can see all the elements of an array in PHP by executing `print_r($_REQUEST);`.  This would give you the exact information each page has access to from $_REQUEST.

Although the caveat here is that every page might have different keys set. Also, it might be beneficial to write this to a temporary logfile, depending on if you are in production.  You wouldn't want  your visitors seeing this output.

Answer (score 0):

I needed it just for the test. Did as you advised, wrote all fiels into a file, used hook 'comment_post' to make sure $_REQUEST has data just after a comment is posted.

```
function rj_comment() {
   // sprint_r as print_r   
   function sprint_r($var) {
    ob_start();
    print_r($var);
    $output=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}   
global $_REQUEST;

$stringData = sprint_r($_REQUEST);

$myFile = "c:/s_request_fiels.txt"; #file name
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");    
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);    
};

add_action ('comment_post','rj_comment');
```

Comment: That’s not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this following question of yours:

> How do they know $_REQUEST has 'contact' field?

My answer is this :

They know because They have **written this hidden input field inside the `<form>` (as the first input field)** like bellow:

```
<input type="hidden" name="contact" value="advanced">
```

They can also enable their custom search template instead of the default **search.php** by writing the following code in **functions.php**

```
<?php
function wpse_load_custom_search_template(){
    if( isset($_REQUEST['contact']) == 'advanced' ) {
        require('advanced-search-result.php');
        die();
    }
}
add_action('init','wpse_load_custom_search_template');
?>
```

Hope it helps you to understand the fact how do they know what field `$_REQUEST` has.